# Issue with Assert.Throws Exception in NUnit testing

Tags: c#, unit-testing, exception, nunit, integration-testing

I am trying out NUnit, Unit Testing and Integration testing for the first time. I have been reading up and doing lots of online courses. As I'm sure you know very well it's something knowing theory and doing it in practice.

I am stuck on a particular test. The application that I have is in C# .Net 3.5.

I am trying to assert that a method with a certain bad input will throw a particular exception.
When I run the method with the same input given to the test the expected exception is thrown.

The method being tested code is:

```
 private static bool FilePathHasInvalidChars(string userInputPath)
{
    try
    {
        Path.GetFullPath(userInputPath);//this is where the warning appears

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.Error(String.Format(
            "The Program failed to run due to invalid characters or empty string value for the Input Directory. Full Path : <{0}>. Error Message : {1}.",
            userInputPath, e.Message), e);
        return true;

    }
    return false;
}
```

I want to check that the above code can catch an exception if the provided input directory is not meeting the criteria.

The Unit test that I have at the moment is:

```
    [Test]
    public void can_throws_exception_for_empty_string()
    {
        var testDirectory = "";
        var sut = new DirectoryInfoValidator();

        Assert.Throws<ArgumentNullException>(() => sut.FilePathHasInvalidChars(testDirectory));
    }
```

The problem I have is that the test allways fails and if I check the return it states that It expected an ArgumentNull exception but was null. I have taken a screenshot of the output from the test:
[image: Asstert.Throws test output]

Any idea what I might be doing wrong? 
EDIT: By the way I have also attempted to use

`[ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentNullException), ExceptionMessage= "Log Message", MatchType=MessageMatch.Contains)]`

Have had same result with that.

On an ending note I am not sure if this is considered an Integration test or a Unit test given that my method uses Path.GetFullPath(string directory).  Anyway my main issue right now is understanding what I am doing wrong. :)
Many thanks,
Jetnor.

UPDATE: After taking all the points into consideration and looking at my system's needs I have decided not to throw an exception. Instead I have decided to create tests which cover the different possible exceptions that can occur in my situation. The test method looks like this:

```
        [Test]
    public void returns_true_for_empty_string()
    {
        var testDirectory = "";
        var sut = new DirectoryInfoValidator();
        var isInvalidPath = sut.FilePathHasInvalidChars(testDirectory);
        Assert.That(isInvalidPath, Is.True);
    }
```

This is a starting point. I inted to use the [TestCase] option by providing all the inputs to one test and checking all of them at the same time. Thanks for your help guys.

Comment: You are catching and silencing the exception -> so the test isn't going to work in the first instance.

Comment: @Arran Thanks for quick reply. Ah that was silly. Is there a way of me being able to check what exception is thrown in the test without throwing it in the original method after catching it?

Comment: As an aside, your unit tests should match the expected functionality of your code - only test that your method throws an exception if you WANT your method to throw an exception. Otherwise, test the return values you want and you'll pick up unintended exceptions along the way.

Comment: @Nward Thanks for the point. Just quick question regarding unit testing. Is there a way of testing Directory and file operations such as Delete all files from a directory or Move all files from one location to another? I know it's a bit unrelated just thought I should ask here before posting another question. :)

Comment: In your setup function, you could create some "dummy" files in a known location, test your various methods on them, and then in your teardown function you can get rid of them (provided your methods didn't already)

Comment: @NWard Ok I will give it a go. I have seen a few resources online just haven't had one good tutorial yet which deals with this kind of stuff. i will have to keep it simple I guess and not complicate it in my head.

Comment: You might find this article to be useful: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549175.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your method FilePathHasInvalidChars does not throw an exception.  An exception is thrown inside of your method, but your method catches and handles the exception.  Your method will always return a valid value.

If you want your method to throw an ArgumentNullException rather than logging and swallowing it, try this:

```
private static bool FilePathHasInvalidChars(string userInputPath)
{
    try
    {
        Path.GetFullPath(userInputPath);//this is where the warning appears

    }
    catch (ArgumentNullException) {
        Log.Error("The Program failed to run due to a null string value for the Input Directory.");
        throw;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.Error(String.Format(
            "The Program failed to run due to invalid characters or empty string value for the Input Directory. Full Path : <{0}>. Error Message : {1}.",
            userInputPath, e.Message), e);
        return true;

    }
    return false;
}
```

With this modification, if userInputPath is null your method will log and re-throw the ArgumentNullException, and your unit test will see the exception and pass.

Answer (score 3):

Your code does not throw an `ArgumentNullException`.  Based on your code, it should never* throw any exception- it should simply return `true` or `false`.

Change your test to the NUnit equivalent of:

```
Assert.IsTrue(() => sut.FilePathHasInvalidChars(testDirectory));
```

Or, if an empty string SHOULD throw an ArgumentNullException, modify the code to something like the following**:

```
private static bool FilePathHasInvalidChars(string userInputPath)
{
    if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userInputPath) throw new
        ArgumentNullException("userInputPath");
    try
    {
        Path.GetFullPath(userInputPath);//this is where the warning appears

    }
    catch (ArgumentException e)
    {
        Log.Error(String.Format(
            "The Program failed to run due to invalid characters or empty string value for the Input Directory. Full Path : <{0}>. Error Message : {1}.",
            userInputPath, e.Message), e);
        throw;    
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.Error(String.Format(
            "The Program failed to run due to invalid characters or empty string value for the Input Directory. Full Path : <{0}>. Error Message : {1}.",
            userInputPath, e.Message), e);
        return true;

    }
    return false;
}
```

*- For a value of "never" that means "so rarely you're unlikely to have to consider it"

**- I haven't tried to compile that, so there may be errors; it's just a starting point.

Comment: Hi Allen, Thank you soo much for your answer. I have got 2 correct answers. Unfortunately I can't mark both. I will put Mark's answer as correct as he got in a few seconds before but again thank you :)